# Странное поведение ListView с использованием SyncAdapter

Tags: android, listview

Есть `ListView`, подгружающий данные из БД SQLite через `SimpleCursorAdapter` в связке с `CursorLoader`. Когда Activity с `ListView` создается впервые вроде бы все нормально, данные выводятся правильные. Но в процессе работы приложения, данные в некоторых элементах `ListView` искажаются и отображается что-то другое, а не то что должно.

Как можно выяснить причину происходящего? Activity запускается с параметром `launchMode` равным `singleInstance`.

**UPD:**
Из JSON данные получаются следующим образом (метод будет доработан в дальнейшем, чтобы схожие элементы получались через цикл, а не вручную каждый по отдельности):

```
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(ex);
                        String set1 = obj.getString("set1");
                        String set2 = obj.getString("set2");
                        String set3 = obj.getString("set3");
                        String exID = obj.getString("exercise");
                        String workWeight = obj.getString("workWeight");

                        if ( exID.equals("3") ) {
                            tvEx.setText("Тяга в наклоне: " + set1 + "/" + set2 + "/" + set3 + " "
                                    + workWeight + "кг");
                        } else {
                            tvEx.setText("Мертвая тяга: " + set1 + "/" + set2 + "/" + set3 + " "
                                    + workWeight + "кг");
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Проблемная JSON-нотация:

```
{
  "exercise":"5",
  "set1":"0",
  "workWeight":"72.5",
  "success":false
}
```

**UPD2:**
Вместо нуля в `set1` подставляется другое значение

Comment: что именно искажается, данные отображаются в других полях или что?

Comment: @ZigZag данные отображаются из какой-то другой записи. Причем только в одном отдельно взятом TextView. Другой TextView в элементе списка с точно таким же механизмом работы ведет себя нормально. Подозреваю, что т.к. данные берутся из JSON - видимо в этом где-то и находится проблема (у некоторых записей в БД что-то формируется в JSON видимо неверно)

Comment: нужен либо код, чтоб что то посмотреть либо обратите внимание как формируется json, может там меняется значение

Comment: @ZigZag добавил код и проблемный JSON

Comment: в коде при обработке значений json  вы сразу устанавливаете значение TextView. что в этом случае делает у вас SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @ZigZag весь этот код находится внутри метода setViewValue(),который получает на вход в качестве параметра этот TextView в классе реализующем интерфейс SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder

Comment: у вас БД локальная или удаленная?

Comment: @ZigZag локальная. А что если в onResume() попробовать вызывать метод forceLoad() ? Ведь проблема именно при возобновлении работы Activity.

Comment: нет, вряд ли.. посмотрите в сторону использования cursor вместо json

Comment: @ZigZag Похоже это связано с тем, что происходит попытка получить значение отсутствующего параметра через методы getType() (set2 и set3 запрашиваются, но таких значений нет фактически) если это подтвердится - то оформлю в качестве решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы возникали из-за того, что методы `JSONObject.getType()` (в данном случае `getString()`) требуют обязательного наличия запрашиваемого из JSON ключа. Проблему можно решить двумя возможными путями:

1. Оставить методы `getType()`, но добавить проверку наличия соответствующих значений в JSON.
2. В качестве альтернативы использовать метод `opt()`, считывающий значения тех ключей, которые могут быть опциональными (т.е. их наличие становится необязательным).